# JQUERY Click function not working inside javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

JQUERY on Click function not working inside JavaScript file of WordPress AJAX Call.
The function alert() outside of the click function is working! But inside not. But everything setup okay for AJAX Call, the script file called correctly in the webpage.

```
var columnfiltertext, column_filter_number;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  //jQuery('span.filter-option').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
  jQuery('span.filter_column.filter_select').click(function(){
    alert("okay");
    column_filter_number = jQuery(this).attr("data-index");
    columnfiltertext = jQuery(this).find("span.filter-option").text();
    if(columnfiltertext)
    {
      if(columnfiltertext != " ")
      {
        //document.cookie = "columnfiltertext= ; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
        //setCookie("columnfiltertext", columnfiltertext , 1);
        //alert("Cookie is: " + getCookie("columnfiltertext"));
        if(column_filter_number)
        {
          alert(column_filter_text); 
          //alert(column_filter_number);
        }
      }
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: example_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        'action': 'example_ajax_request',
        'fruit' : fruit,
        'nonce' : example_ajax_obj.nonce
      },
      success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        //console.log(data);
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown){
        //console.log(errorThrown);
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
    });  
  });
});
```

Filename: simple-ajax-example.js

Answer (score 0):

If your alert("okay") is not reachable, then it might be the case that your selector i.e `jQuery('span.filter_column.filter_select')` might not be returning anything. You may try that in your browser console if it returns anything, just past `jQuery('span.filter_column.filter_select')` in console if your DOM is already rendered.

Comment: It was not the case! jQuery('span.filter_column.filter_select') is working fine, but I aaded the code in footer.php it does working, but separate javascript file dont as in Ajax Wordpress call